# Oracle: are objects created by sys in a schema the same as objects created by that user?

Tags: oracle, permissions

For example, are there any differences between:

```
SCOTT@ORCL> create index a_idx on a(x);
```

and

```
SYS@ORCL> create index scott.a.idx on scott.a(x);
```

Comment: A good read for you, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2659418700346202574 and http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/164126/0/

Answer (score 1):

Apart form all the **DOs** and **DONTs** about using **SYS** in this case is  that "**if you connect as sysdba, your schema name will appear to be SYS**".

Phil's answer demonstrates it. A nice quote by Thomas Kyte on a similar [question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2659418700346202574) -

> In general, unless the documentation tells you, you will NEVER LOG IN
>   as sys or system, they are our internal data dictionary accounts and
>   not for your use. You will be best served by forgetting they exist.
>
> sysdba and sysoper are ROLES - they are not users, not schemas. The
>   SYSDBA role is like "root" on unix or "Administrator" on Windows. It
>   sees all, can do all. Internally, if you connect as sysdba, your
>   schema name will appear to be SYS.
>
> In real life, you hardly EVER need sysdba - typically only during an
>   upgrade or patch.

We keep saying the following so many times -

> - Never ever use SYS (or SYSDBA) but for maintenance purpose (startup, shutdown, backup, recover)
> - SYS/SYSDBA is special
> - SYS/SYSDBA is Oracle proprietary (try to open a SR/TAR starting with "i did that with SYS/SYSDBA" and you'll see the immediate answer)
> - SYS/SYSDBA does not act like any other user
> - When you use SYS/SYSDBA Oracle deactivates some code path and activates others
> - Whatever you do with SYS/SYSDBA will neither validate nor invalidate the same thing with any other user.
>
> NEVER EVER use SYS/SYSDBA for anything that can be done by another
>   user.  Use SYS/SYSDBA ONLY for something that can't be done by someone
>   else.

You might also like to read [this](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/164126/0/).

Answer (score -1):

I'll start my answer with this:

As a general rule: Never, ever, create objects as the user `SYS`/`SYSTEM` (or any other  "internal" Oracle user) unless directed to do so by Oracle support.

A simple test case shows that there's a big difference, due to ownership.

As `SCOTT`:

```
SQL> create table a ( b number );

Table created.

SQL> create index a_idx on scott.a ( b ) ;

Index created.

SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> select owner from all_indexes where table_name = 'A';

OWNER
------------------------------
SCOTT

SQL> drop index a_idx;

Index dropped.
```

As `SYS`:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> create index a_idx on scott.a ( b ) ;

Index created.

SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select owner from all_indexes where table_name = 'A';

OWNER
------------------------------
SYS

SQL>
```

This obviously causes problems due to ownership etc, as well as the data residing in a tablespace that you don't want user objects belonging in (from above example, because we didn't specify a `TABLESPACE` clause:

```
SQL> select owner, tablespace_name from all_indexes where table_name = 'A';

OWNER                          TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            SYSTEM

SQL>
```

Comment: Although not going to disagree what you put here, note that the OP DID indicate a schema name in his create index .. so NO, in his case, the index does create under SCOTT, not SYS. No argument on anything else though ;)

Comment: @Ditto it's not possible to qualify with a SCHEMA name, as the OP suggests: `SQL> create index scott.a.idx on scott.a(x);
create index scott.a.idx on scott.a(x)
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00969: missing ON keyword


SQL>
`

Comment: Sure it is .. just did in Oracle 11. under schema "test": create table junk (id number);   under "SYS": create index test.junk_idx on test.junk(id);   index shows as "owned" by "test".  In your example, you didn't prefix the index name with the user, so it creates under SYS.

Comment: Hmm, I see, probably the formatting style used ... I'm just using "schema.index" .. not the "schema.table.index" OP used and you used above.  That's probably throwing it for a loop ;)   `SQL> create index test.junk_idx on test.junk(id);

Index created. `  I read that as a typo though, since his first example was "a_idx" .. not "a.idx" ;)